# Extracting an expression matching a pattern from a large expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a Mathematica expression that contains a single square root, schematically

```
expr = a / (b + Sqrt[c]);
```

where `a`,`b`,`c` are large expressions. I would like to extract the expression under the sqrt, for instance by matching to a pattern, something like

```
Match[expr,Sqrt[x_]] // should return c
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Theoretically, this should work correctly:

```
extractSqrt = Cases[ToBoxes@#, SqrtBox@x_ :> ToExpression@x, Infinity] &;

extractSqrt[expr]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to change the assignment to `expr`, you can do this:

```
expr = Hold[a / (b + Sqrt[c])];

Cases[expr, HoldPattern @ Sqrt[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

The `Hold` in the assignment statement prevents Mathematica from applying any simplifications to the expression.  In this case, `Sqrt[c]` gets "simplified" into `Power[c,Rational[1,2]]`.

The `HoldPattern` is essential in the `Cases` expression to prevent the same simplification from happening to the pattern being matched.

Answer (score 5):

I await a few examples, but in the meantime, try:

```
Cases[expr, x_^(1/2 | -1/2) :> x, Infinity]
```

The standard internal form for Sqrt(x) is `Power[x, 1/2]`.

Comment: @Sjoerd I imagine in fails in a variety of cases. :-/

Comment: @Sjoerd I made a change to catch more cases.

Comment: @Sjoerd, please see my other answer.  I don't have time to test it, but I think it is the solution.  Please leave a comment if there is an obvious failure.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, of course there's the trivial case of a=0...  %^)  Not necessary to think of a/(b + Hold[Sqrt[c]]) either, is it? (just kidding). Other than that, it looks like you hammered it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My last comment pertains to the answer it is attached to. Thought you meant the update with "other". Didn't see the second answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd or Wizard: Could either of you point out why it fails for `b=0`? As a simple test case, `Trace[Cases[b + c, x_ :> x, Infinity]]` gives `{{Infinity,Infinity},Cases[b+c,x_:>x,Infinity],{b,c}}`, whereas   `Trace[Cases[c, x_ :> x, Infinity]]` gives `{{Infinity,Infinity},Cases[b+c,x_:>x,Infinity],{}}`. Why is it an empty list in the second case and not `{c}`?

Comment: @yoda In the original pattern there was no negative exponent and a/(0+Sqrt[c]) is coded as Times[a,Power[c,Rational[-1,2]]]. Your 2nd example fails because Infinity means the levels from 1 to infinity whereas c is at level 0. Use {0, Infinity} instead. In b+c, b and c are at level 1, because they are in Plus[b,c]. Hence it works in this case.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Ah, didn't catch that it converted it to `^-1/2`. Nice explanation! Thanks :)

Comment: @Wizard: Would `Denominator[expr]` inside of `Cases` make it faster, especially since OP mentioned `a`,`b` and `c` are large expressions or is `Denominator[]` an expensive operation?

Comment: @yoda I didn't even consider execution time.  Usually manipulations like this are done infrequently (meaning, not as part of some repetitive program), at least for me.  I wouldn't expect either method to be particularly slow, but when I have some time I'll test them, unless someone else has done it first.