# Prepend complex I to a sub-expression of an expression?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider this example:

```
expr = a (1 + b + c d + Sqrt[-2 d e + fg + h^2] + a j );
```

Now I'd like to insert a complex `I` before the term in the square root and retain the rest of the expression. I know that `expr` has only one `Sqrt` term in it. So I tried the following:

```
ToBoxes@# /. SqrtBox@x_ :> RowBox[{I, " ", SqrtBox@x}] &[
  expr] // ToExpression
Out[1] = $Failed
```

**Q1:** Why does it fail?

The workaround was to use a different variable and then replace it with `I` as so:

```
(ToBoxes@# /. SqrtBox@x_ :> RowBox[{k, " ", SqrtBox@x}] &[expr] // 
   ToExpression) /. k -> I
```

[image]

**Q2:** Why does this work?

**Q3:** Are there alternate/better ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts of a box expression that aren't structural need to be strings. So you want

```
In[1]:= expr = a (1 + b + c d + Sqrt[-2 d e + fg + h^2] + a j );

In[2]:= ToBoxes@# /. SqrtBox@x_ :> RowBox[{"I", " ", SqrtBox@x}]&[expr]//ToExpression
Out[2]= a (1 + b + c d + I Sqrt[-2 d e + fg + h^2] + a j)
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it partially. Why does it work then in the second case, i.e. `k` (not a string) instead of `I`?

Comment: @yoda: I think it's because `I` (not the string) gets interpreted as `Complex[0,1]`...  Only atomic-type (not exactly those that are `AtomQ`) objects can be put in there without being a string or in a RowBox etc...

Answer (score 4):

Errr

```
expr /. Sqrt[x_] -> I Sqrt[x]
```

?

**Edit**

If you want to consider the 1/Sqrt[x] case try:

```
expr/.Sqrt[x_]->I Sqrt[x]/.Power[x__,Rational[-1,2]]-> 1/( I Sqrt[x])
```

Comment: Yes, I was using that earlier, but I learnt from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682963/extracting-an-expression-matching-a-pattern-from-a-large-expression/5683056#5683056) that it fails in certain cases. For example, your method fails for `expr=1/Sqrt[a+b]`. I admit, my example did not specify this corner case, but I was more keen on understanding _why_ it fails with `I` and not with other symbols.

Comment: +1 If the context is such that you know ahead of time that you are going to be manipulating the expression, you can wrap it in `Hold` and then use the straight-forward transformation: `expr = Hold[...]; expr /. x_Sqrt :> I x // ReleaseHold`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have accepted Simon's because my primary confusion was why `I` fails and `k` worked, and his answer clarified that.

Answer (score 1):

Simon is correct that you need the quote marks.  Also, your replacement can be simplified:

```
ToBoxes@expr /. x_SqrtBox :> RowBox@{"I", x} // ToExpression
```